# Make an object react to a sound in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, animation, audio

I have a speaker and I need this speaker moves with a sound. I need to simulate the real world speaker vibration generated by the low and mid frequencies.

Does not have to be soo realistic what I whant to know is how I can play a sound and get son mumerical value usefull for apply numerical size transformation to the speaker.

Cheers!

Comment: Comment instead of answer because it doesn't address Flash directly.  If you get the rest of your animation done in Flash and then do the sound matching in After Effects, AE has a function to keyframe audio -- it will generate a numerical value at every frame according the audio level. You can then apply a spatial transform to a jaw or mouth shape as a function of that audio value.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the amplitude of a sound in AS3 using the `SoundMixer.leftPeak` and `SoundMixer.rightPeak` methods: there's a nice example [here](http://theflashblog.com/?p=234)...